# Is there a faster way to get UNION ALL behavior in Postgres?

Tags: performance, postgresql, union

I have a table (t0), in my Postgres DB, with data that looks something like this:

```
t1_id  t2_id
1      1      
2      1
2      1
4      null
4      null
5      null
```

And I have a query to return my desired results of:

```
t1_id  t2_id
1      1
4      null
5      null
```

My query looks something like this:

```
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2_id) t1_id, t2_id
  FROM t0
  WHERE t2_id IS NOT NULL
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1_id) t1_id, t2_id
  FROM t0
  WHERE t2_id IS NULL
)
```

Is there a faster way to do an operation like this? It's not too bad, but I'm doing it in several places (with joins) and all these repeated queries seems to slow stuff down a bit. Seems like there must be a better way.

Here's the query in fiddle form: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3603